How can I teleport a player to the Nether?
I'm new at Minecraft Modding and I created a simple mod that checks if the player is in The End when they log in, if not they are teleported to a random coordinate there. I was trying to develop the same mod but to teleport the player to the Nether but I keep getting the "Invalid Player Data" error. Could anyone help me?
The event log in for the End Dimension: 
​
​
 public void onPlayerLoggedIn(PlayerEvent.PlayerLoggedInEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof ServerPlayer player && !player.level.isClientSide) {
            ServerLevel endDimension = player.getServer().getLevel(Level.END);
            if (endDimension == null) {
                return; 
            }
            if (player.level.dimension() != Level.END) {
                if (sharedSpawnPosition == null) {
                    sharedSpawnPosition = findSafeIslandPosition(endDimension);
                }
                BlockPos spawnPos = addRandomOffset(sharedSpawnPosition);
                setPlayerRespawnPoint(player, Level.END, sharedSpawnPosition);
                player.changeDimension(endDimension);
                player.teleportTo(spawnPos.getX() + 0.5, spawnPos.getY(), spawnPos.getZ() + 0.5);
            }
        }
    }

​

The code with the Nether Version:
​
    public void onPlayerLoggedIn(PlayerEvent.PlayerLoggedInEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof ServerPlayer player && !player.level.isClientSide) {
            ServerLevel netherDimension = player.getServer().getLevel(Level.NETHER);
            if (netherDimension == null) {
                return; 
            }
            if (player.level.dimension() != Level.NETHER) {
                if (sharedSpawnPosition == null) {
                    sharedSpawnPosition = findSafeIslandPosition(netherDimension);
                }
                BlockPos spawnPos = addRandomOffset(sharedSpawnPosition);
                setPlayerRespawnPoint(player, Level.NETHER, sharedSpawnPosition);
                player.changeDimension(netherDimension);
                player.teleportTo(spawnPos.getX() + 0.5, spawnPos.getY(), spawnPos.getZ() + 0.5);
            }
        }
    }

​

I tried several ways to use the changeDimension() function or teleport the player without doing any verification and I still get the same error
